# How to set top property of dynamic control from the code-behind so that it is rendered at the bottom of the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show a flowchart at the end of an asp page. 
Does something like  top : Last exist?

```
List<chartItem> lstChartItems = new List<chartItem>() { new chartItem { id = "node-start", top:*Last* , content = "Start" } }; 
            int nodenumber = 1;
            foreach (string psName in lstProcessSchemeTypeNames)
            {
                lstChartItems.Add(new chartItem { id = "node-" + nodenumber, content = psName });
                nodenumber++;
            }
            lstChartItems.Add(new chartItem { id = "node-end", content = "End" });
```

Comment: what type of flowchart you want to show would you please add some code

Comment: That List object is certainly not a control. What control will you be using to display in the webpage?

Comment: this list sets the attributes of a set of div controls